# Heroku run rake on remote app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I'm using Heroku Postgres on an app that I'm hosting on Nitrous.io. The app runs, but gives me the following error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist                                                                                                             
LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass                                                                                                    
                                    ^                                                                                                                      
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),                                                                                          
                 pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod                                                                    
          FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d                                                                                                       
            ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum                                                                                               
         WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass                                                                                                            
           AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped                                                                                                         
         ORDER BY a.attnum
```

So after reading around I've tried running `heroku run rake:db reset --app app_name` but I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!                                                                                                                                                  
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)                                                                                  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2367:in `raw_load_rakefile'                                                                                                  
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'                                                                                             
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'                                                                                        
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'                                                                                                      
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'                                                                                                                
/usr/local/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

I'm confused as to what I'm supposed to do since I'm not hosting the app on Heroku. I just need to get my tables set up for my app. Here's my database.yml:

```
development:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
pool: 5
database: <%= ENV['CHAKRA_DEV_DATABASE'] %>
username: <%= ENV['CHAKRA_DEV_USER'] %>
password: <%= ENV['CHAKRA_DEV_PASSWORD'] %>
host: <%= ENV['CHAKRA_DEV_HOST'] %>
port: <%= ENV['CHAKRA_DEV_PORT'] %>
```

My .bashrc as the following at the bottom:

```
### Heroku Postgres Details                                                                                                                                    
export CHAKRA_DEV_HOST=ec2-******.compute-1.amazonaws.com                                                                                               
export CHAKRA_DEV_DATABASE=df2cokjfj0k4vu                                                                                                                      
export CHAKRA_DEV_USER=zgwgf****rhyn                                                                                                                          
export CHAKRA_DEV_PORT=5432                                                                                                                                    
export CHAKRA_DEV_PASSWORD=JAImDWqN****4k7VOhUpLmbn
```

I've tried running heroku run rake db:migrate from within my app's folder, but it doesn't work. Instead I've tried using the name of the Heroku postgres DB where the app name is supposed to go. Any advice?

Comment: Try with `heroku run rake db:drop` then `heroku run rake db:create` if it will succeeds then `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

Comment: It fails, saying "resource not found". I ran the rake db:drop command from INSIDE my Rails app. Any idea?

Comment: Why in database.yml I only see configuration for dev environment. On Heroku your app everything should run on production. Please fix this and let us know.

Comment: Still getting the "no rakefile found" error message

Answer (score 1):

Since your app is not hosted at Heroku trying to run your `rake` tasks inside Heroku will not work.  You need to run the `rake` task from Nitrous.io.  Or if you can run you code locally, since you have your development config setup to point at your Heroku db you may be able to just run `rake db:reset` on your local machine.